# Why this example doesn't exhibit visibility problem in concurrent code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility

I tried to avoid all common pitfalls of writing a code demonstrating the visibility problem in concurrent access in multi-threaded code. But still, the tested variable always shows the updated value; it behaves like it's `volatile`.

I am avoiding all causes of *happens before*, avoiding all synchronization tools like `CountDownLatch`, not using `Thread.sleep()` or even `System.out.println()` because they all may have hidden synchronization triggering *happens before* consequences I am trying to avoid here.

The only *happens before* action is the start of the updating thread, but that happens before the test, so it shouldn't interfere with the test.

I got me curious. What else I may have overlooked?
What prompts JMV to synchronize the tested variable?

Here is the code:

```
int a = 0;

@Test
public void testVisibility() {

    new Thread(() -> {
        // First thread:

        // write to A new value as soon as possible; second thread should be still 
        // idly spinning at this time 
        a = 100;

        // delay ending the thread until after the test is done, 
        // ending thread has "happens before" implications we want to avoid here  
        idle(500_000_000, dummy1); 

        // this is never printed because testing framework interrupts it while 
        // still idling; this line is never reached.
        System.out.println("thread finished"); 
    }).start();

    // Second thread:
    // For this I reuse main test thread; JUnit assertions has to be done in the main tests thread
    // otherwise they are not (normally) propagated up making this test to always pass. 

    // Ensure that following code is ensured to be run after a is set to 100
    // we cannot use sleep() as it may cause "happens before" internally  
    // It must be large number, as starting thread is a relatively slow process, 
    // much slower than my dummy loop, on my hardware it must be > 1_000
    idle(10_000, dummy2);  

    // It's expected to see stale value of 0 here, because it is not volatile and was modified in a different thread
    // Yet it always see the updated value :(
    int a_ = a;
    assertEquals(100, a_);

    // it's safe to use println() now, after the test
    System.out.println(dummy1); // usually prints number a bit above 10_000
    System.out.println(dummy2); // usually prints number a bit above 10_000
}

private long dummy1 = 0;
private long dummy2 = 0;

private static void idle(long lengthOfDelayInNumberOfSpins, long dummy) {
    for (int i=0; i < lengthOfDelayInNumberOfSpins; i++) {
        dummy++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

My question is not about if it cannot happen, I have no doubts that it can; my questions is about how to make it happen more reliably. To my best knowledge my code should exhibit the visibility problem, and if not, then why not?

Since I posted this questions at least two possible causes popped up in my head:

- The HotSpot compiler kicks in; the loops are definitively evaluated as hot code. As a side effect of the compilation might be that variables are synchronized (possibly simply by putting them to main memory because of the compilation). - *this can be fixed by pre-warming the code*.
- The lag between writing to A in Thread 1 an reading it in Thread 2 is long enough for OS to interleave the execution with another process, possibly some system service; context switches like that are known to cause large cache invalidation, causing variables have to be re-read from main memory causing A having the updated value in Thread 2. - *this can be fixed only by bringing writing to A more close to reading from A, finding such ideal spin numbers would be very fickle*.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. You have not personally experienced a currency problem. That does not mean that it is not possible.

Comment: Having happens-before relationship gives you guarantees. Not having it doesn't give any guarantees. It's possible that the issue you're trying to exhibit will show up at random when running statistically significant number of times.

Comment: `System.out.println(dummy1); // usually prints number a bit above 10_000` well, it should print zero since you never re-assign either of them.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, Re, "show up at random...." In some particular run-time environment, or never in a different run-time environment, or always in yet another run-time environment. My favorite bugs always were the ones that never showed up in the test harness, didn't show up when the customer evaluated the software,... didn't show up until the customer came to depend on the product, and then one day, they upgraded their OS, or they moved it to to a different hardware platform, and then boom!

Comment: @SolomonSlow, yes, exactly what I was describing. These are the nasty ones.

Comment: My question is not about if it cannot happen, I have no doubts that I can in my scenario; my questions is about how to make it happen more reliably. To my best knowledge my code should exhibit visibility problem, and if not then why not?